# how to get values using again MAX and MIN function in oracle sql?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

I got following results with this SQL Query:

```
SELECT Code,
 CASE
      WHEN MAX(running) = MIN(running) THEN MAX(running)
      ELSE MAX(running) - MIN(running)
 END
"RUNNING",
 date
FROM table
GROUP BY date;
```

Result:

```
Code    Running     Date
CC4       123       1/1/2018
CC4       12        1/11/2018
CC4       12000     4/2/2018
CC4       1000      4/10/2018
```

User Select From date (1/1/2018) To date (4/10/2018)

Codes are same in "Code" Column. I want Use again Max and Min Function in above query to achieve only one result for "Code" Column

How to achieve this target in oracle SQL?

Comment: Your first query is invalid and won't even run on Oracle.  What is the actual query which generated the output?

Comment: How many such codes are there?  Show us how your original table actually looks like and what's your final expected output. [Your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53588099/how-to-avoid-0-values-using-min-and-max-function-in-sql)  did not mention code column.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just want to `GROUP BY code`:

```
SELECT Code,
       (CASE WHEN MAX(running) = MIN(running) THEN MAX(running)
             ELSE MAX(running) - MIN(running)
        END) as "RUNNING"
FROM table
GROUP BY code;
```